# Formulário angular com laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Eu tenho duas tabelas: Convites e Processo.

Um processo pode ter um convite , assim como um convite pertence a um processo.

Desta maneira fiz o relacionamento no banco onde a tabela Convite tem o campo processo_id referenciando de qual processo é.

Sendo assim eu cadastro os processos, e quando eu quero cadastrar um convite eu uso o combobox abaixo para escolher de qual processo
é o convite.

O select carrega normalmente os dados dos processos cadastrados.

Inclusive coloquei a tag  para mostrar o id do processo só para saber qual id esta referenciando.

mas já tentei de todas a maneiras conhecida (por mim) para salvar no banco e não consigo, ele não salva
e não me da retorno de erro, simplesmente quando clico no botão salvar ele não faz nada.

estou começando em angular, e utilizo ele junto com o laravel, poderiam me dizer ou indicar um tutorial 
onde  mostra-se qual a maneira correta de se salvar os dados de um  com angular.

```
 <div ng-controller="procconvitController">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nº. Processo:</label>
    <select ng-model="convite.processo_id" ng-options="processo.id as processo.numero for processo in processos">
    </select> <br>  
    <small><% convite.processo_id %></small>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<% convite.processo_id %>">
</div>
```

Obrigado pela atenção

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>

$scope.salvar = function(){
    if($scope.convite.id){
        conviteService.edita($scope.convite).success(function(res){
            $scope.listar();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    }else{
        conviteService.cadastra($scope.convite).success(function(res){
            $scope.listar();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    }
}

app.factory('conviteService',function($http) {
return {
    lista: function(){
        return $http.get('/numeros/convites');
    },
    cadastra: function(data){
        return $http.post('/numeros/convites', data);
    },
    edita: function(data){
        var id = data.id;
        delete data.id;
        return $http.put('/numeros/convite/'+id, data);
    },
    exclui: function(id){
        return $http.delete('/numeros/convite/'+id)
    }
}
```

});

```
// Cadastrando Convite
public function novo(Request $request)
{
    $data = sizeof($_POST) > 0 ? $_POST : json_decode($request->getContent(), true); // Pega o post ou o raw

    return DB::table('convites')
        ->insertGetId($data);
}
```

esse é todo o caminho feito para salvar os dados na tabela, funcionava até eu relacionar a tabela e incluir o campo processo_id na tabela convite.

fiz também os métodos nos models:

```
class Convites extends Model
{


    public function processo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('confin\Processo');
    }

}

class Processo extends Model
{
     public function convite()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Convite');
    }
}
```

tentando novamente percebi alguns erros no console

```
angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.salvar (app.js:49)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14605), <anonymous>:4:209)
at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15694)
at callback (angular.js:25622)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17444)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17544)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25627)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (app.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.g.handle (app.js:3)
```

(anonymous) @ angular.js:13708

@radamesrf

esse é todo meu código, conheço bem pouco de angular, e adaptei um código que peguei pronto, como eu disse antes de fazer o relacionamento funcionava.

```
// Controller
```

app.controller('convitesController', function($scope, conviteService) {
    $scope.listar = function(){
        conviteService.lista().success(function(data){
            $scope.convites = data;
        });

```
    // ordenar
    $scope.ordenar = function(keyname){
    $scope.sortKey = keyname;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
}

$scope.editar = function(data){
    $scope.convite = data;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}

$scope.salvar = function(){
    if($scope.convite.id){
        conviteService.edita($scope.convite).success(function(res){
            $scope.listar();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    }else{
        conviteService.cadastra($scope.convite).success(function(res){
            $scope.listar();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    }
}

$scope.excluir = function(data){
    if(confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir?")){
        conviteService.exclui(data.id).success(function(res){
            $scope.listar();
        });
    }
}
```

});

um dos problemas eu resolvi, era um erro básico de fechamento de tag, mas agora eu não consigo passar os dados de um controller para outro, pois se coloco o input fora do procconvitController ele não pega os dados, mas também com o input dentro ele não passa para o convitesController.

Resolvi o problema de passar os dados, usei o #rootscope

Comment: O problema está em "if($scope.convite.id){" no seu método de salvar. O convite em seu escopo tem o campo "id" definido? Como vc está inicializando este "$scope.convite"?

Comment: não sei o que fazer fora isso @radamesrf, pois utilizei um código de modelo, ainda estou aprendendo sobre angular.